# Elegant zebra striping for Grid?

Tags: grid-layouts, display

Some users like zebra striping in grids (see this [ux posting in SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3562/to-use-or-not-to-use-zebra-stripes-or-alternating-row-colors-for-tables), whence I got the image below).

[image: Example of zebra-striped grid]

Of course, it's easy to manually shade and style the cells of a `Grid` in Mathematica (see [this documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) and the image below), but the provided options are almost too general and a solution that is 'just general enough' for zebra striping didn't come to me immediately.

Zebra striping seems like such a common practice that I was rather surprised not to see any examples or mention of it in the documentation, let alone a top-level option for it in Grid. Before diving in, I thought I'd quickly ask the community for an "elegant" solution. Of course, *elegant* is difficult to define, but you all probably know it when you see it.

[image]

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RkvqR.png) is in the docs for `Grid`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Grid[RandomInteger[1, {5, 4}], 
  Background -> {None, {Lighter[Blue, .9], {White, GrayLevel[.9]}}}, 
  Dividers -> All
]
```

[image]

Comment: Great to have this as a concrete example of how to program the abstract `spec`s in the documentation.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin I actually adapted this example from the second example in the Applications section.

Comment: Oh, nice! I missed that one.